# How to rearrange an equation with matrices to isolate a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm trying to get y on a side by itself from the following equation:

$ β = (X^TC^{-1}X)^{-1}X^TC^{-1}y $

where

- $y$ is an $n$ x $1$ vector
- $X$ is an $n$ x $2$ matrix in which the first column contains 1's and the
  second column contains variables
- $β$ is a 2-parameter vector
- $C$ is an $n$ x $n$ diagonal matrix
- $^T$ indicates the matrix is transposed

I'm using R, and have so far been able to establish that $ X^TC^{-1}y $ is equal to `solve(solve(t(X)%*%solve(C)%*%X),B)`. The result is a 2-parameter vector. However, I can't figure out how to isolate y.

For some context, this is the generalized least squares solution to a phylogenetic regression, where x is the independent variable, y is the dependent variable, C is the variance-covariance matrix of species relatedness, and β are the parameters for the regression.

I apologize if I have butchered the terminology here. I have zero background in linear algebra. Hopefully this is a straightforward question. Let me know if anything needs clarification. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I found the function `Solve` in the R package `limSolve`, which gives the generalized inverse solution:

```
Solve(solve(t(X)%*%solve(C)%*%X)%*%(t(X)%*%solve(C)),B)
```

The resulting calculated $y$ is not the original $y$, but does yield the correct $β$ when plugged back into the original equation. This is certainly progress, but unless I'm missing something, it seems there are **many** solutions to the problem, and this instance of matrix algebra is a one-way street, unless there is perhaps some way to externally impose additional limits.

Comment: Could you please add LaTex to the question? It makes it more readable.

Comment: You can not just invert it. I remember that such systems used to be solved by use of the Moore-Penrosepseudoinverse. But this is a long time ago. Maybe http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/ginv.html does what you want?

Comment: That looks like it could do it, although I'm not quite sure how to go about it. I thought it might be as simple as `ginv(t(X)%*%solve(C)) %*% solve(solve(t(X)%*%solve(C)%*%X),B)` to give y, but no such luck.

Comment: Looks like the model for your regression was $\boldsymbol{y=X\cdot b}$.  The least-squares solution for $\boldsymbol{b}$ is the equation you've posted above.

Comment: But is it possible to back-calculate the **raw** values of $y$ (i.e., not the model values of $y$) given $b$, $C$, and $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are faced with a general linear model, with some covariance matrix $C$, which is not the identity matrix: $y_i=\beta_1 + \beta_2 x_i + \varepsilon_i, \ i=1, \dots, n$, and $\sigma^2 C$ is the covariance matrix of the multivariate random variable $\varepsilon$. Here, $\beta = (\beta_1; \beta_2)^T$.

The formula for $\beta$ you are using is only valid if $C$ is invertible (i.e. there is an inverse matrix $C^{-1}$; $C$ needs to have full rank for that), and if the matrix $X^TC^{-1}X$ is invertible as well. A criterion for that is that $X$ needs to have full rank, in this case $2$. $X$ has rank $2$ if not all explanatory values $x_i$ are the same. This formula yields an *estimate* $\hat \beta = (\hat \beta_0 ; \hat \beta_1)^T$ of $\beta$, and *predicted values* $$\hat y_i = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 x_i.$$ (Note: Only if $C$ would be the identity matrix , the so-called homoskedastic case, these predictions would have the *least squared errors* $\Sigma_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat y_i)^2$; for the case of heteroskedasticity, these estimate for $\hat \beta$ is the best linear unbiased estimator, but doesn't necessarily minimize the error squares.)

Since the prediction equation is always linear in $\beta$, this prediction will only coincide if there is a perfectly linear dependence between $y$ and $\beta$. This is in general not the case, so the predictions will not be equal to the actual values. It's usually not desired, nor possible to reconstruct the actual values of $y$ from the coefficient $\beta$ and the values of $x$. However, if we have $\hat \beta$ and some $x$-Value for which we can't measure the $y$, we can use the prediction equation above to get a linear prediction of the value of $y$.